# Grunt Run in a For Loop

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I'm new to grunt.

I have a gruntfile that works for a single build.   There are several target that are chained together to complete the process.   The problem is that I need to create several different builds using variable data.  I'm trying to figure out how to do this in my gruntfile.

Today, to do a build, I just need to run

```
grunt --foo=bar build
```

or

```
grunt --foo=baz build
```

What I'd like to, and have tried to do, is create a build-all target that uses an array to define the foo data, like so:

```
grunt.registerTask('build-all', function() {
    var foos = ["bar", "baz"];
    for (var i in foos) {
        grunt.config.set("foo", foos[i]);
        grunt.task.run("build");
    }
});
```

From the looks of things, it seems that the run task is non-blocking.  And that means that "foo" is being set to "baz" before the first run, running it twice for the same value.

Is there a better way to set arguments/options in this situation?   Or to run the task in a blocking way?

Comment: Looks like you'll need to use something like [grunt-multi](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-multi)

Comment: Thanks, that actually worked for me.  Unfrotunately, I can't accept a comment as an answer, so no points for you :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I recently ran up against this same issue, and wrote [grunt-galvanize](https://github.com/dylancwood/grunt-galvanize.git) to help with this. Here's how it works, applied to your example:

```
grunt.registerTask('build-all', function() {
    var foos = ["bar", "baz"];
    var galvanizeConfig = [];

    for (var i in foos) {
        galavanizeConfig.push({configs: {foo: foos[i]}});
    }
    grunt.option('galvanizeConfig', galvanizeConfig);
    grunt.task.run(['galvanize:build']);
});
```

This will run the *build* task with each of the options/configs specified in `galvanizeConfig`.

PS. I also use grunt-multi for cases where I desire concurrency, but grunt-galvanize is a much simpler tool for cases where concurrency is not required.